# Looping JSON array with nested JSON objects

Tags: php, laravel

How can I loop over the json payload object and correctly assign the nested `user_info` and `address` json objects to the `users` tables `user_info` and `address` columns? `email` and `password` are correctly assigned however since `user_info` and `address` are json objects its not working

user table

```
email (string), 
password (string), 
user_info (json), 
address (json)
```

JSON Payload

```
{
    email: 'testing@gmail.com',
    password: 'password',
    user_info: {
        first_name: 'testing'
    }
    address: {
        zip_code: 12345
    }
}
```

controller

```
protected function createOrUpdate(Request $request) {
    $user = new User();
    $uCols = [
            'email',
            'password',
            'user_info.first_name',
            'address.zip_code',
        ];

    $input = $request->only($uCols); // input is the json payload above

    foreach($uCols as $column) {
        if(array_key_exists($column, $input) && !empty($input[$column])) 
        {
            $user->$column = $input[$column]; //email and password are correctly assigned 
        }
    }
    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to update my fillable columns array to only include the column names and not the properties like `user_info.first_name`

```
$uCols = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_info',
        'address',
    ];
```